# Methods to quantify lead(II) concentration in water on the ppm/ppb level

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, water, analytical-chemistry, water-treatment

While there are several ways to quantify metal concentrations in water, a lot of them are only specific to select metals. For example, there is the orthophenanthroline method for quantification of Fe(II) concentrations via spectroscopy. How can lead(II) concentrations be determined using a similar spectrophotometric method?

If spectroscopy isn’t the most efficient way to quantify these concentrations, is there a better way to do it?

The salt used to release $\ce{Pb^2+}$ ions into solution is $\ce{Pb(NO3)2}.$

Answer (score 2):

Russian interstate standard GOST 18293-72 "Drinking water. Methods for determination of lead, zinc and silver content" ([PDF in Russian](http://docs.cntd.ru/document/gost-18293-72)) suggests to use [sulfarsazene](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/13955960) (plumbone), which forms orange-yellow complex with lead(II).
Reported method sensitivity (spectrophotometry): $\pu{0.5 μg L-1}.$

A brief review in English [[1](https://doi.org/10.1515/REVAC.1986.8.4.313), p. 315]:

> To determine lead in solid particles of industrial facilities, natural waters, biological objects and salts, sulfarsazene is used (4''-nitrobenzene-1'',4-diazo-amino-1,1-azobenzene-2''-arsono-4-sulfoacids).
>   While it is less sensitive than dithizone , it has a number of advantages: it is water-soluble, easy to handle and needs no cyanide as masking agent.
>   But, it has insufficient reaction selectivity.
>   Manganese, nickel, copper, zinc, mercury, cadmium, iron, zirconium, and other elements interfere with the determination. The methods developed on the basis of sulfarsazene require a preliminary ion separation; for instance, lead is separated by extracting with dithizone solution in carbon tetrachloride …
>
> Study of the reaction of sulfarsazene with lead ions points to simultaneous participation of the lead cation with triazene and arson groups in complex formation.
>   Polarographic investigation confirmed the existence of lead bonds with the *o*-arsonotriazene group of the reagent, and cleared up the azo-group contribution to the formation of the complex which may be due to coordinative bonding with lead atoms.
>   The role of the nitrogroup as an electrophilic substituent that improves the mobility of the hydrogen atom of the aminogroup was experimentally confirmed.
>   The structure of the resultant compound is as follows:
>
> [image: sulfarsazene lead complex]

GOST 18293-72 also includes polarographic method for lead detection using the dropping mercury electrode.
Reported method sensitivity: $\pu{10 μg L-1}.$

#### References

1. Roeva, N. N.; Savvin, S. B. Spectrophotometric Determination of Minute Lead Contents of Natural and Industrial Objects. *Reviews in Analytical Chemistry* **1986**, 8 (4). DOI: [10.1515/REVAC.1986.8.4.313](https://doi.org/10.1515/REVAC.1986.8.4.313).

Comment: Does the method sensitivity refer to the concentration limit in which the coloured complex follows Beer’s law?

Comment: Moreover, is there a purchase link online? The name seems obscure.

Comment: @Thunderbolt114 Yes, the limits are for the quantitative determination, and the calibration curve is plotted using lead(II) nitrate at $λ_\mathrm{max} = \pu{500 nm}$.

Comment: @Thunderbolt114 As for buying, it seems that you would need to go with Russian or Chinese suppliers. Being listed in [CRC Handbook of Organic Analytical Reagents](https://books.google.com/books?id=RPqeQLr3PyQC&pg=PA202&lpg=PA202&dq=sulfarsazene&ots=9TSMGcxKpx&sig=ACfU3U2xVThMYoI3XO1KYbS4U6e3LbdAyw&hl=en#v=onepage&q=sulfarsazene&f=false), sulfarsazene still isn't a popular reagent in the West.

Comment: I’ve been trying to search for an affordable pricing for this reagent but haven’t stumbled upon any suppliers. Might you know of any site/supplier?